# Incosistent countdowntimer output issue

Tags: python, performance, time, countdowntimer, consistency

```
import time
    
while True:
    start=time.time()
    time.sleep(2)
    end=time.time()
    howlong = end - start
    print(howlong)
```

I coded this so that I can have something happen 2 seconds later.
the expected output is 2.00
yet the output varies between 2.00 and 2.02 on my pc.
is there anything I can do so that I always have less than 2.01 every time?
I haven’t tried anything since I’m a noob.

Edit: Never mind I switched to this:

```
while True:
    start = time.time()
    goal = start+2
    while True:
        end = time.time()
        if end >= goal:
            print(end-start)
            break
```

The results are more consistent.

Comment: as you are calculating 'howlong' after the sleep, any chance the delay is the time between?

Comment: well that's the issue, even if it was the time in between why does it vary? the time in between should be the same. so it should give me a consistent 2.01 or 2.02 not vary.